# GSON: expecting a JSON response, but API returns HTML error page on internal errors (500)

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a Retrofit + Gson setup, which leaks the connection due to

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

The REST API I work with returns a HTML error page instead of a JSON response on internal server errors (500).

Is there a way to handle this case on a client level? Let's say if I receive an error response with status code 500, Retrofit or GSON should not try to deserialise the response.

Comment: What about searching first on how to get the response code from a retrofit request and handle accordingly? You didn't need to post this question

Comment: Wow, really? Obviously if you knew what you are talking about you'd know that by the time I can access a status code provided by retrofit, the process would fail on a serialisation and I need to handle it on a lower level. Just go and have a nice day buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `OkHttpClient` as your http client for Retrofit you can add an interceptor to the `OkHttpClient` and if the request returns an error you can do something with it. Example:

```
public class InternalServerErrorInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
            //do whatever you want to do with the response here
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

...

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new InternalServerErrorInterceptor())
    .build();

RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()  
        .setClient(new Ok3Client(client))
        .setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL); //Ok3Client: https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit1-okhttp3-client
```

Comment: By the way just to be clear, this interceptor example actually finishes the request line and gets the response - so if you have multiple interceptors, this should be the last one added.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I've been looking for.